# Http protocol for chatting server

Tags: android, network-protocols

I am working on a project like whatsApp. I am confused about the the protocol for chatting. can I use Http protocol for communication? your suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Try XMPP. Use a server like Openfire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something more interactive, so that you don't need to poll for new messages. Try xmpp. WhatsApp uses the same protocol (well a little other encoded) and even Google Talk. Alternative you could try websockets.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use http protocol for communication.
use JSON or xml or etc.
But, before set or make webserver.
otherwise you can use GCC(Google Cloud Message) for sending message between android device.

Comment: No that is a bad idea. Your GCM account will probably been banned if you send too many messages at once. Let's say you have 1000 users which is not much and all of them send a message at the same second I don't believe that Google would accept that. GCM should been used for a one to many communication not one to one.

Comment: @rekire Your comment is correct in C2DM. But, GCM is different. Using GCM, sending 1000 message once a time. And limit of send message count is expire. I can hear some app is service using GCM and APNS.

Comment: And if user know other user's Application's GCM assign key, user direct sending message is possible.